# "TypeError: expected string or buffer" with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, urllib

I am relatively new to Python and Beautifulsoup. I need to simply parse the response of a certain request for which I am using urllib2 (for request and response) and BeautifulSoup4 for parsing.

I have used these previously without any problems. However, for this particular project I am strangely getting errors.

Below is a part of the code that I have written :

```
class WebLogin(object):
def __init__(self, username, password, targetSite, loginUrl):
    # url for website we want to log in to
    self.base_url = targetSite;
    self.loginUrl = self.base_url + loginUrl;

    # user supplied username and password
    self.username = username;
    self.password = password;

    # file for storing cookies
    self.cookie_file = 'login.cookies'

    # set up a cookie jar to store cookies
    self.cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(self.cookie_file)
    # set up opener to handle cookies, redirects etc
    self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(
        urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
        urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
        urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
        urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)
    );

    # pretend we're a web browser and not a python script
    self.opener.addheaders = [
    ('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0')
    ];

    # open the front page of the website to set and save initial cookies and to retrieve the csrf token (__FK is the csrf token here) required for login
    response = self.opener.open(self.base_url);
    self.cj.save();
    print response.info().get('Content-Encoding');
    initialResponse = response.read();
    print "\nResponse received for \n\n",initialResponse;

    # parsing the response for csrf token
    soup = BeautifulSoup(initialResponse);
```

Now when I am printing 
**print "\nResponse received for \n\n",initialResponse;** above, I get a proper HTML response. 
However, when I am trying
**soup = BeautifulSoup(initialResponse);** above, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

Please let me know, what is going wrong here ? What am i missing ? Why am I not able to make a soup out of response.read() ?

I have tried using .decode('utf-8') in case that was fiddling around with things, but that hasn't helped the situation.

here is the error again in case the above snapshot was not legible :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "flipkartLogin.py", line 64, in 
>       WebLogin(username, password, targetSite, loginUrl);
>
> File "flipkartLogin.py", line 43, in **init**
>       soup = BeautifulSoup(initialResponse);
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/**init**.py", line 172, in **init**
>       self._feed()
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/**init**.py", line 185, in _feed
>       self.builder.feed(self.markup)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 146, in feed
>       parser.feed(markup)
>
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 114, in feed
>       self.goahead(0)
>
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 158, in goahead
>       k = self.parse_starttag(i)
>
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 324, in parse_starttag
>       self.handle_starttag(tag, attrs)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 48, in handle_starttag
>       self.soup.handle_starttag(name, None, None, dict(attrs))
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/**init**.py", line 298, in handle_starttag
>       self.currentTag, self.previous_element)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 749, in **init**
>       self.name, attrs)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/**init**.py", line 160, in _replace_cdata_list_attribute_values
>       values = whitespace_re.split(value)
>   TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: The error message is unreadable as a screenshot. Please post it as text.

Comment: I upvoted otibom's comment, but want to reiterate.  Your blue-background screenshot is illegible.  Please give us a larger version or paste the test!!

Comment: What does `initialResponse` look like when printed

Comment: Try specifying the parser: `soup = BeautifulSoup(initialResponse, 'html.parser')`